# How to use Idhttp within TThread Properly?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, idhttp

I currently have this TThread to download some images to a desk, here is the threading Code:

```
type
  TDownloadUpdateAnimateEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; AAnimationname: String;
    var AAnimationUrl: String) of object;

type
  TDownloadanimation = class(TThread)
    private
      FOnUpdateAnimate: TDownloadUpdateAnimateEvent;
      FAnimationname : String;
      FAnimationUrl : string;
      FPathImage : String;
      ImageName: string;
      PathURL: string;
      FFileNameImage: string;
    procedure DoUpdateAnimate;
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
    public
      constructor Create(AAnimationname:string; AAnimationUrl: string; AOnUpdateAnimate : TDownloadUpdateAnimateEvent; APathImage : string);
      property PathImage: string read FPathImage;
      property FileNameImage: string read FFileNameImage;
  end;

{ TDownloadanimation }

constructor TDownloadanimation.Create(AAnimationname, AAnimationUrl: string; AOnUpdateAnimate : TDownloadUpdateAnimateEvent; APathImage : string);
var
  URI: TIdURI;
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  FOnUpdateAnimate := AOnUpdateAnimate;
  FPathImage := APathImage;
  FAnimationname := AAnimationname;
  FAnimationUrl := AAnimationUrl;
  URI := TIdURI.Create(FAnimationUrl);
  try
    ImageName := URI.Document;
    PathURL := URI.path;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(URI);
  end;
end;

procedure TDownloadanimation.DoUpdateAnimate;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnUpdateAnimate) then
    FOnUpdateAnimate(self, FAnimationname, FFileNameImage);
end;

procedure TDownloadanimation.Execute;
var
  aMs: TMemoryStream;
  aIdHttp: TIdHttp;
  IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  path: string;
  dir: string;
  SPEXT : String;
  itsimage: string;
  responsechk: Integer;
begin
  dir := AnsiReplaceText(PathURL, '/', '');

  if (ImageName = '') then
  begin
    exit;
  end;

  path := PathImage + ImageName;

  if fileexists(path) then
  begin
    FFileNameImage := path;
    if Assigned(FOnUpdateAnimate) then
    begin
      Synchronize(DoUpdateAnimate);
    end;
    exit;
  end
  else
    if not fileexists(path) then
    begin
      aMs := TMemoryStream.Create;
      aIdHttp := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
      IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
      try
        IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
        IdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
        aIdHttp.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams] + [hoNoProtocolErrorException];
        aIdHttp.IOHandler := IdSSL;
        aIdHttp.AllowCookies := True;
        aIdHttp.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
        aIdHttp.HandleRedirects := True;
        aIdHttp.RedirectMaximum := 3;
        try
          aIdHttp.Head(trim(FAnimationUrl));
        except
        end;
        itsimage := aIdHttp.Response.ContentType;
        responsechk := aIdHttp.ResponseCode;

        if responsechk <> 200 then
        begin
          FFileNameImage := 'error';
          if Assigned(FOnUpdateAnimate) then
          begin
            Synchronize(DoUpdateAnimate);
          end;
          exit;
        end;
        if (itsimage = 'image/gif') then
        begin
          try
            aIdHttp.Get(trim(FAnimationUrl), aMs);
          except
          end;
          aMs.SaveToFile(path);
        end;

        try
          if aIdHttp.Connected then
            aIdHttp.Disconnect;
        except
        end; 

     finally
       FreeAndNil(aMs);
       FreeAndNil(IdSSl);
       FreeAndNil(aIdHttp);
     end;
  end;

  FFileNameImage := path;

  if Assigned(FOnUpdateAnimate) then
  begin
    Synchronize(DoUpdateAnimate);
  end;
end;
```

and here is the Form that call Create Thread

```
For i := 0 To imageslist.Count-1 do
begin
  Animatref := 'ref';
  Animaturl := imageslist.Strings[i];
  URI := TIdURI.Create(Animaturl);
  try
    ImageName := URI.Document;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(URI);
  end;

  if (ExtractFileExt(ImageName) = '.gif') then
  begin
    if Fileexists(CheckPath+ImageName) then //if image exists then do something and dont start the Thread To download it 
    begin
      //do something
    end 
    else 
    if NOT Fileexists(CheckPath+ImageName) then // not found on desk and start to download
    begin
      addanimation(Animatref, Animaturl);
    end;
  end;
end;


procedure Tform1.addanimation(animationname, animationurl: string);
var
  Pathanimate:string;
begin
  Pathanimate := appfolder;
  Downloadanimation := TDownloadanimation.Create(animationname, animationurl,  UpdateAnimate, Pathanimate);
end;
```

And when the application Destroy I call:

```
if Assigned(Downloadanimation) then
begin
  Downloadanimation.Terminate;
  FreeAndNil(Downloadanimation);
end;
```

But I got run time error each time I close the application after downloading Thread Fired. Is this because i download multiple images at the same time? if so is there better way to write the thread like waiting after the download image finish then start new download if this was the real issue .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you signal the thread to terminate, call `WaitFor()` on it **before** freeing it:

```
if Assigned(Downloadanimation) then
begin
  Downloadanimation.Terminate;
  Downloadanimation.WaitFor; // <-- add this
  FreeAndNil(Downloadanimation);
end;
```

Also, your Form's logic has the potential of running multiple download threads at the same time, but you are only keeping track of the last thread that is created.  And you are not freeing it when it is finished, only when the app exits.  You should either set `FreeOnTerminate=True` on each thread, or else store all of the threads in a `TList` and use their `OnTerminated` event to know when each thread is finished so you can remove it from the list and free it.

On a separate note, your thread's `Execute()` logic can reduce its network traffic a little by removing the call to `TIdHTTP.Head()` altogether, and instead set the `TIdHTTP.Request.Accept` property to `'image/gif'` when calling `TIdHTTP.Get()`.  The server *should* report a `406 Not Acceptable` response if the requested resource exists but is not a GIF, anything else would report an HTTP error, just like `TIdHTTP.Head()` would have.  There is no point in sending a `HEAD` request in this example.

Comment: Thank you very much thats helpful but a note isn't `waitfor` will freeze the application ?

Comment: `WaitFor()` waits for the thread to be fully terminated.  That *can* cause UI freezes if you misuse it, yes.  But if you design your thread correctly, and manage it correctly, that won't be a problem.  Besides, another problem with your original example is that you are using `Synchronize()`, which waits for the main thread to process the sync, but if the app is already in the process of exiting when `Synchronize()` is called then you can easily cause a deadlock in both threads.  At least `WaitFor()` processes `Synchronize()` requests while waiting for the thread to terminate.

Comment: Hi again remy i have an old question and its not answered yet i still search for an answer about it i try to follow your suggestion about my client code and how to write it safe and better i think you are the only one who can help me  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686389/how-to-use-criticalsection-with-idtcpclient-that-running-in-tthread